# Mysterious settings for Internet usage

Tags: networking, internet, broadband

Recently I had an issue with my broadband internet connection. The support guy from my ISP came and fiddled with some settings. I don't remember what and from where he was tweaking the settings. The only thing I remember is seeing a windows dialog with a drop down that had values with  like 10 kbps - 100 Kbps, Upto 1 Mbps. The only thing I am sure is these settings are Windows settings and not from any software. Later it turned out that the actual problem was with the internet wire somewhere else. However now I want to change those settings again because it seems Internet is not as fast as was earlier. Does anyone have an idea what these settings could be ?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to your vague description, guessing is all that is possible. Please describe in greater detail what the tech did and on what device (your PC, his PC, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, but it could be the NIC [Network Interface Card] properties sheet.

Right click My Computer, select Properties.
In the pane that opens select Device Manager.
From that, reveal Network Adaptors [If more than one, select the one you use]
Right click, Properties, then Advanced.
Scroll to Speed & Duplex, select.
Change the Speed back to Auto Negotiation.

[image]

Picture is Win 7. Others should be similar, only cosmetically different.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like he may have been messing with your heuristic settings. This can conceal high latency and other network bottlenecks from the user. It was originally created to conceal the high latency to other Continents when web browsing ECT. I've seen it fail a couple times now, but only in windows 7 x64.

Start type cmd in the search bar, then right click on the command prompt icon. Run it as administrator. Type the following commands:

netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled

netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

netsh int ip set global taskoffload=disabled

Reboot and test your connection again.

To reinstate heuristics run these commands again replacing disable with enable.

Here is a reference article if you are interested:
https://www.duckware.com/blog/how-windows-is-killing-internet-download-speeds/index.html